# Android Venmo App - Top Friends Algorithm?

Tags: applications

I'm a heavy venmo user and I'm wondering how they determine your so called "top people" when you start to make a payment. I see people I haven't sent money to in close to a year, people I'm not friends with anymore, and people I've exchanged probably a dollar with. Meanwhile, my roommates and girlfriend are so far down the list it's not even worth scrolling, so I just type their names every time.

I don't think it's by:

1. Most recent transactions
2. Amount of money exchanged
3. Largest single transaction
4. Likes or comments

That's just judging based on my personal knowledge of my friend list.